# ASP Core scaffolding error - package restore failed on a clean new project

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I tried doing Identity scaffolding on my existing ASP Core app and I get this error:

*There was an error running the selected code generator:
'Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'WebApplication1'.'*

[image]

take note that this is a clean new project, nothing was modified, I am using VS2022 and .NET 6, the project template I used had the Authentication Type set to "Individual Accounts"
[image]

is there any way around this to fix this bug?

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue resolved by:
Going to Tools->NuGet Package Manager->Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...

I had updates for EntityFrameworkCore that needed installing.
Also had updates for RazorRunTimeCompilation.

Each are now on the current 6.0.10 version.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use dotnet rider's scaffolding feature instead, it works with no problems